# Print variable in Twig containing sub-variables which need to be printed in turn

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a complex content generation system in Symfony 4 which needs to render a Twig template. In a nutshell, there is a CMS which allows admin users to write templates.

E.g. the admin can create a page using a WYSIWYG editor

```
<h1>Admin Content</h1>
<p> {{ variable1 }}</p>
```

The Controller will then call Twig's render method.

```
$templateParameters = [
    'content' => $this->content, // this is obtained directly from the content that the Admin saved in the database (e.g. see html content above)
    'variable1' => 'Test', 
    'anotherVariable' => 100.00 // in this scenario this variable will not be used 
];

return $this->container->get('twig')->render(
    sprintf('@pages/%s', $this->templateFilename()), // the twig file name
    $templateParameters
);
```

Finally, in the Twig template file there will be a single tag

```
<div class="content">
    {{ content|raw }}
</div>
```

However, the problem with this is that the content displayed will be exactly the one persisted in the database (as entered by the admin).

E.g. the template will render as

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Admin Content</h1>
    <p> {{ variable1 }}</p>
</div>
```

So, how can I get nested variables to be replaced with the array of context parameters? Is this possible in Twig, or should I write some sort of regex in my Controller/Services to parse the content here? (if that's the case, could I make use of Twig's methods (e.g. render)?

Comment: Either with your own extension or built in, you'll probably want to experiment with [`template_from_string`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/template_from_string.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render a string template in this way

```php
<?php

$loader = new \Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader([
    'content.html' => $this->content,
]);
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);

$renderizedContent = $twig->render('content.html', ['variable1' => 'My value']);

return $this->render("my_real_template.html.twig", [ 'content' => $renderizedContent ]);
```

Check here for more doc https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#twig-loader-arrayloader